# C# S3 API DeleteObject throwing 409 Conflict: The bucket your tried to delete is not empty

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

When attempting to delete an object via the S3 API (AWSSDK.S3 v3.1.0.0)
I receive the following error messaging

```
[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.]
[AmazonS3Exception: The bucket you tried to delete is not empty]
```

I am NOT attempting to delete a bucket, nor do I wish to delete a bucket.

This is the code in my class:

```
    public static void Delete(string filename)
    {
        using (AmazonS3Client client = new AmazonS3Client(ACCESS_KEY_ID, SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
        {
            var deleteRequest = new DeleteObjectRequest();
            deleteRequest.BucketName = BUCKET;
            deleteRequest.Key = Path.GetFileName(filename); //ensure only the filename is sent as key, not the path
            client.DeleteObject(deleteRequest);
        }
    }
```

The API is pretty simple, the calling conventions are straight forward, any ideas why I would be getting a failure to delete a bucket while calling DeleteObject?

Comment: "*I am NOT attempting to delete a bucket, nor do I wish to delete a bucket.*"  I'm not familiar with Amazon S3, but the code you posted sure looks like you're trying to delete something.....

Comment: It is trying to delete an object not the bucket.

Comment: Your code looks a lot like [the documentation suggests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingOneObjectUsingNetSDK.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/facepalm

Stupid mistake, the calling code is passing NULL for the filename.  Simply passing the correct filename solved the problem.

Comment: Yep, that would do it.  Unlike what you might expect based on typical web site behavior, buckets don't have a place for a file at the root `/` object.  The root object is the bucket itself, so your request with an empty(ish) path was inadvertently trying to delete the bucket.